# How to force a folder to download in php?

Tags: php, download, directory

I know how to force a file and something like that to download but don't know is it even possible to force a folder to download. If yes, what would be the content type?

Comment: Zip folder or iterate through each file...

Comment: just normal folder not a zip folder

Comment: You can't send a folder. All you can do is send files.